# How to connect a C# console application with a database stored in a .sql file

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a console application project with perform some tasks as creating some structures from a database stored in a .sql file. I already import its data with a MySQL client. I use NHibernate. My question is: 
What are the actions that i have to perform to work with data stored in the database from the console application?

Comment: The steps are pretty much the same regardless of the type of application.

Comment: So, this question doesn't actual have anything to do with a sql file?  It sounds like you've already solved that part...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have NHibernate setup and you need to know how to get data out of it, into your application.

This tutorial has everything you need:

http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx